# Layer draws over other elements and ignores z-index

Tags: html

On a web I have a transparent layer to cover the page on click and only show a few page elements.  But it doesn't matter what I have for the z-index. That layer covers one element I would like to show.  The element with id `player` should be shown over the layer.  What should I specify differently for `layer` and for `player` for this?

```
  <div id="layer" style="width: 100%; height: 100%; visibility: visible; z-index: 99;"> </div>

  <div id="page" style="margin: 0 auto; position: relative; top: 80px;"> <!-- Begin page div -->

  <div id="player" style="width: 506px; height: 377px; border: 2px solid white; z-index: 99999; display: inline; float:left; margin-top: 12px; margin-left: 12px; margin-right:0px; overflow: hidden;">
```

The styles for `layer` are these.

```
#layer {
    position: absolute; 
    top: 0px; 
    left: 0px; 
    width: 100%; 
    height: 100%; 
    background: black; 
    filter:alpha(opacity=80); 
    opacity: 0.80; 
    z-index: 999;" 
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set `position: relative;` for #player div.

Answer (score 0):

One thing to check is that you should have "position:relative;" applied to the parent container of these divs for the z-indexing to be recognized and applied.